# Label on top on input that uses flex

Tags: html, css

Im using flex to format input on a row format. But right now im trying to put label on top of those inputs and its not working. Im tried using display block and floating left or right but still remains on the left side. How should i style label so it floats to the top of those inputs?

This is the snippet:

```css
.box {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
    
    .inside-box {
        max-width: 51rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .form-group {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .razao-social-content {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
        /* grow shrink basis */
    }
    
    .rua-content {
        flex: 6 1 auto;
    }
    
    .municipio-content {
        flex: 4 1 auto;
    }
    
    .numero-content {
        flex: auto 1 auto;
    }
    
    .bairro-content {
        flex: 4 1 auto;
    }
    
    .telefone-content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    .email-content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    .categoria-content {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
    }
    
    .controlador-content {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
    }
    
    label {}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="inside-box">
        <form action="" class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="lb" for="name">Razão Social</label>
                <input class="razao-social-content" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Informe o seu nome" required>
                <label class="lb" for="cnpj_distribuidor">CNPJ</label>
                <input class="cnpj-content" type="text" id="cnpj_distribuidor" placeholder="CNPJ" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="rua">Rua</label>
                <input class="rua-content" type="text" id="rua" placeholder="Nome da rua" required>
                <label for="municipio">Município</label>
                <input class="municipio-content" type="text" id="municipio" placeholder="Nome do Município" required>
                <label for="numero">Número</label>
                <input class="numero-content" type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Número da Residência" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="bairro">Bairro</label>
                <input class="bairro-content" type="text" id="bairro" placeholder="Nome do Bairro" required>
                <label for="uf">Estado</label>
                <input class="uf" type="text" id="uf" placeholder="Estado" required>
                <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                <input class="cep-content" type="text" id="cep" placeholder="CEP" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="telefone1">Telefone</label>
                <input class="telefone-content" type="text" id="telefone1" placeholder="Telefone" required>
                <input class="telefone-content" type="text" id="telefone2" placeholder="Telefone" required>
                <input class="telefone-content" type="text" id="telefone3" placeholder="Telefone" required>
                <input class="telefone-content" type="text" id="telefone4" placeholder="Telefone" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="email1">Email</label>
                <input class="email-content" type="text" id="email1" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input class="email-content" type="text" id="email2" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input class="email-content" type="text" id="email3" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input class="email-content" type="text" id="email4" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <label for="categoria">Categorias</label>
                <input class="categoria-content" type="text" id="categoria" placeholder="Informe as Categorias" required>
                <label for="data_constituicao">Data Da Constituição</label>
                <input class="data-content" type="date" id="data_constituicao" placeholder="Data da Constituição" required>
                <label for="data_cvm">Data da CVM</label>
                <input class="data-content" type="date" id="data_cvm" placeholder="Data do CVM" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="controlador">Controlador</label>
                <input class="controlador-content" type="text" id="controlador" placeholder="Nome do Controlador" required>
                <label for="cnpj_controlador">CNPJ</label>
                <input class="cnpj-content" type="text" id="cnpj_controlador" placeholder="CNPJ" required>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This image link shows how I want it to be

https://www.figma.com/file/nuLJYzwr2LtoJxt4rPKDaI/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: @Pete placeholders should not be a substitute for proper labels in the first place. (If anything, in this example, _different_ placeholders should be chosen, perhaps. It should not _repeat_ what the label already “explained” about the field’s meaning, but rather give an example value.)

Comment: If i use flex-direction: column on .row both inputs and labels will be on colum directions and i want the input to stay on a row direction.

Comment: https://www.figma.com/file/nuLJYzwr2LtoJxt4rPKDaI/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to change the HTML to do that I think. Each label and input should be in a separate div.

Comment: Change how?????

Comment: Edited comment.

Comment: just wrap each label and input in a new div and make the label block

Comment: this work on placing the label on top of input, but the input lost it's flex: 2 1 auto; property

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap label and input inside a div and add :

```
.row > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: this work but the inputs lost it's sizes, if you check the css razao-social-content has flex: 2 1 auto; and when i do like you says it shrinks.

Comment: Manage to get this working? I've hit the same issue